# How do i add a customized CellEditorListener to my JTable?

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecelleditor

I start typing my code:

```
private void addMyCellEditorListener() {

    class MyCellEditorListener implements CellEditorListener
    {
        public MyCellEditorListener() {}

        public void editingCanceled(ChangeEvent e) {}

        public void editingStopped(ChangeEvent e) {
            if(row == 0 && column > 0)
                rechargeTableWithFindedResults(graphicTable.getValueAt(row,column));
            else
                dataTable.setValueAt(graphicTable.getValueAt(row,column),row,column);
        }
    };

    .... addCellEditorListener(new MyCellEditorListener());
}
```

I would like my `graphicTable` to detect data changes into its cells by giving it a customized `CellEditorListener`, but I really can't understand how to add it.  I tried several times with a code like the following:

```
DefaultCellEditor editor = new DefaultCellEditor(new JTextLabel());
editor.addCellEditorListener(new MyCellEditorListener());
this.graphicTable.setCellEditor(editor);
```

... or:

```
this.graphicTable.setCellEditor(this.graphicTable.getCellEditor().addCellEditorListener(new MyCellEditorListener()));
```

... however these techniques give me a `NullPointerException` in both cases.

I have looked around through forums to get a solution, but they are just getting me more confused.

Every hint would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is incorrect. **You can easily detect data changes in your `TableModel`, specifically in `setValueAt` method**. Once you detected the change and reacted on it, you have to call one of the `fireTable..` methods to let table and all other listeners know that data changed

There no need to assign any listeners to cell editors at all.

Comment: I think i need some listener added to the JTable as i have to use the first row as like a "search box"; for example if i type a key word in the cell (0,1) the JTable have to detect the user inputed string and use it to recharge the table with the results that it find on certain data pre-charged from the TableModel.
I would like to detect data changes not on TableModel, but on the JTable graphic grid, as JTable uses its own getValueAt() and setValueAt() methods. Thanks for reply

Comment: Swing is designed using MVC model. So JTable is a a view/controller and your table model is a data. The table does not keep any data - model does. Whenever you make edit in the cell the setValueAt method of your model is called.
This is why my advice is still to use the model. You can easily check the row index to make sure you only do your "recharge" for first row.